# Why is my VB app invisible to the screen recorder?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I have written a VB application in VS2010.  When I try to record its operation for a demo video with Windows Media Encoder x64 or Apowersoft free screen recorder, I get a recording of everything on the desktop except my application. It's like the application is invisible to the recorder.  It has worked in the past (2 weeks ago). It must be something I have done but I'm baffled. Is there a "feature" in VB that can prevent you from recording the Form?

BTW, a still screen capture works fine and sub forms I bring up are captured. Only the main form is invisible to the recorder.

Comment: Using the Opacity or TransparencyKey properties?

Comment: 1) Windows 7 x64?  Are you running either/both as administrator?  2) Last time it worked, were you using it it as a (stand-alone) exe or in debug mode via Visual Studio?  3) is it built in debug or release mode?

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for your help and time.
Not a VS or VB problem after all. What I found was that windows 7 was switching me from Aero Theme to Windows 7 Basic.  The message that showed up was that I was low on display memory.  (A quick pop-up in the bottom right corner that I was ignored during the recording).  However, I have 4.75 G of display memory?
BTW on a video conf call it produced the same invisibility "feature" until I found the Theme switch.
I haven't actually fixed anything but now know to watch for the tell tale screen blink as it switches mode.  I pause the recording, and switch it back before restarting the recording.  Got through the recordings I needed for now.  I was using MS Media Encoder.  I have now replaced it with Adobe Premier elements but haven't tried it yet to see if I still have the problem.  Need to get the "how to" videos out the door first.

Thanks again. I have read many of your Answers to others in the past that have helped me solve numerous other VB and VS problems.

Michael

Answer (score 0):

That's weird since it's recording forms from the application and not other forms (main form) from the same application.
Make sure you run the recorder as administrator and not the application.